# read the .asm output of idaPro in FASM

Tags: assembly, ida, fasm

Can anyone help me out understanding the different assembly versions of `idaPro` and `FASM`. As I am parsing the `.asm` file as the output of idaPro using FASM, it seems that in many cases there are differences in assembly versions. Do these two have different versions of assembly for x86 windows?